# refreshing GoogleMap on Angular 2 which is on a hidden component

Tags: google-maps, angular

Here is my problem : Maps inside a hidden div are not shown

possible solution :

```
<div [hidden]="!showMap">
    <sebm-google-map #myMap></sebm-google-map>
</div>
<button (click)="showMap = true; myMap.triggerResize()">resize</button>
```

This could work with a simple 1 variable, in my case I have dynamic creation of theses div, so i cannot point to #myMap so easily

Comment: Is this about calling `myMap.triggerResize()` on one specific `<sebm-google-map>` of a set of elements created using `*ngFor`?

Comment: I don't know about angular 2, but there's probably an equivalent of ng-class.  Make a new class that has `visibility:hidden;position:absolute;z-index:-100;`, and add or remove it with ng-class.  My thought is that if you use visiblity:hidden. It might work because it still may render the div.  If that doesn't work you could also try `opacity:0`.  The other stuff is to make it show up behind everything else so it looks like its not there.

Comment: is created by *ngFor

Comment: And you want to call `triggerResize()` on all of them, or just one specific at a time?

Comment: buttons are created dynamically and represents headings of an accordion . So on click, a hidden div is display with a its nested map. 1 map should be refreshed at a time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is for calling `triggerResize()` on all `<sebm-google-map>` elements:

```ts
<div *ngFor="let item of items"> <!-- just some ngFor for demo -->
  <button #myMap (click)="showMap = true; doTriggerResize()">resize</button>
</div>
```

```ts
@ViewChildren('myMap') viewChildren:QueryList;

doTriggerResize() {
  this.viewChildren.toArray().forEach((e) {
    e.triggerResize();
  });
}
```